# memcpy a void pointer to a union

Tags: c, unions

Code:

```
union foo
{
    char c;
    int i;
};

void func(void * src)
{
    union foo dest;
    memcpy(&dest, src, sizeof(union foo));   //here
}
```

If I call `func()` like this:

```
int main()
{
    char c;
    int i;
    func(&c);
    func(&i);
    return 0;
}
```

In the call `func(&c)`, the size of `c` is less than `sizeof(union foo)`, which may be dangerous, right?

Is the line with `memcpy` correct?  And if not, how to fix it?

What I want is a safe call to `memcpy` that copy a `void *` pointer to a `union`.

---

A little background: this is extracted from a very complicated function, and the signature of `func()` including the `void *` parameter is out of my control. Of course the example does nothing useful, that's because I removed all the code that isn't relevant to provide an example with minimum code.

Comment: this code doesn't make sense. what do you want to do?

Comment: The memcpy is NOT fine. Undefined behavior is not restricted to only *writing* in memory regions you don't own. *Accessing* them **at all** is undefined behavior. That it may not crash (and on some platforms it *will*) makes no difference.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Did you mean the code example did nothing useful? If that's the case, that's because I only extracted the part that I have doubts with. I added a little background, I don't know if that's enough.

Comment: why not cast the void pointer to `union foo` and assign the field of `c` instead of `memcpy`

Comment: @MYMNeo This would solve the example I provided, but the real code is much more complicated, e.g, the elements of the `union` are `struct`. A version using `memcpy` is preferred.

Comment: no, I meant it doesn't make sense. you should copy the size based on source, not the target (as the target is always large enough). Note: I would suggest running your original code with valgrind, or a similar tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the line with memcpy correct? And if not, how to fix it?

you should pass the **size** of memory pointed by void pointer so you can know `src` has this much size so you just need to copy this much of data...

**Further more to be safe**  you should calculate the size of destination and based on that you should pass size so  **illegal access** in reading and writing both can be avoided.

Comment: @MvG oh thanks...after almost 2 years i understand this things.

Comment: "*... so you can know dest has this much size so you just need to copy this much of data ...*": Is this a typo? You are referring to `src` as `dest`, aren't you? As per your 1st sentence, this: "*... pass the size of destination ...*" should read: "*... pass the size of source ...*", shouldn't it?

Comment: This is incorrect.  The size of the destination is hardcoded in the function which provides the destination, and so always correct.  The possible concern is with assuming the size of the source leading to a theoretically illegal access.

Answer (score 6):

> In the call `func(&c)`, the size of `c` is less than `sizeof(union foo)`, which may be dangerous, right?

Right, this will lead to undefined behaviour. `dest` will likely contain some bytes from memory areas surrounding `c`, and which these are depends on the internal workings of the compiler. Of course, as long as you only access `dest.c`, that shouldn't cause any problems in most cases.

But let me be more specific. According to the C standard, writing `dest.c` but reading `dest.i` will *always* yield undefined behaviour. But most compilers on most platforms will have some well-defined behaviour for those cases as well. So often writing `dest.c` but reading `dest.i` makes sense despite what the standard says. In this case, however, reading from `dest.i` will still be affected by unknown surrounding variables, so it is undefined not only from the standards point of view, but also in a very practical sense.

There also is a rare scenario you should consider: `c` might be located at the very end of allocated memory pages. (This refers to memory pages allocated from the operating system and eventually the memory management unit (MMU) hardware, not to the block-wise user space allocation done by `malloc` and friends.) In this case, reading more than that single byte might cause access to unmapped memory, and hence cause a severe error, most likely a program crash. Given the location of your `c` as an automatic variable in main, this seems unlikely, but I take it that this code snippet is only an example.

> Is the line with `memcpy` correct? And if not, how to fix it?

Depends on what you want to do. As it stands, the code doesn't make too much sense, so I don't know what correct reasonable application you might have in mind. Perhaps you should pass the `sizeof` the `src` object to `func`.

Comment: By memory mapping unit, do you mean Memory Management Unit (MMU) ?

Answer (score 1):

The `memcpy` is fine. By passing the address of the smallest member of the union, you will end with garbage in the larger member. A way to avoid the garbage-bit is to by default make all calls to `func` - which I assume you do control - use only pointers to the larger member - this can be achieved by setting the larger member to the smaller one: `i = c` and then call `func(&i)`.

Comment: The [`memcpy()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memcpy.html) isn't fine, because what's being passed to copy from _isn't_ a union.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson: mem = memory - does not require the content pointed-to to be anything ...

Comment: Certainly it does. If you pass a pointer to a one-byte object and tell `memcpy()` to pull four bytes out of that pointer, that's Undefined.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson: that definitely is PIBCAK :)

Answer (score 1):

`func` itself is ok.

The problems lies in whether the caller really makes sure that the memory referenced when calling `func()` is at least `sizeof(union foo)`.

If the latter is always the case, everything is fine. It is not then case for the two calls to `func()` in the OP's example.

If the memory referenced when calling `func()` is less then `sizeof(union foo)` then `memcpy()` provokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Actually, no, it isn't okay.  It assumes things about the readability of the next 3 bytes, which the caller doesn't guarantee.

Comment: Didn't I wrote this? @ChrisStratton  (And why do you refer to "*three*" bytes?)

Answer (score 0):

Since you know what and what size to copy, why not give a more explicit function, let the function know how to copy the right size of memory which void pointer pointed to.

```
union foo
{
    char c;
    int i;
};

void func(void * src, const char * type)
{
    union foo dest;

    if(strcmp(type, "char") == 0){
      memcpy(&dest, src, 1);
    }else if(...){

    }
}
```

Comment: Arg! Don't use strings for such things! If you have to pass type identification information, use an enum. But all that is needed here is the size of the type, so that's what I'd suggest you pass.

Comment: I agree with you, I just want to give a example, strings comparison is not very good.